# Matlab error: input argument not defined

Tags: matlab-guide

I wrote the function as:

```
function f = factorial(x) 
f = prod(1:x);
f =factorial(5);
end
```

But when I tried running it, it says input argument not defined.
What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a function which recurses endlessly.

```
f = factorial(5);
```

in the third line will call your function again, which will then again call your function once it reaches the third line, which then again will call your function... so it will never get done.

When implementing a recursive solution you need to provide a base case. Here's an example for calculating factorials.

```
function f = factorial(x)
    if x == 0 % this is the base case
        f = 1;
    else
        f = x*factorial(x-1); % this is the recursive case
    end
end
```

example:

```
>> factorial(5)       
ans =
   120
```

As for your

> input argument not defined

problem, you need to tell us what you actually used as an input argument. For the above example, any* integer `x>=0` should work.

*as long as `f` has enough bytes to hold the result.